# How to find existing Hybrid Connection RelayId using Pulumi.Azure?

Tags: azure, pulumi, azure-hybrid-connections

I have an existing App Service and an existing Hybrid Connection, I was able to get all the parameters I need to create a new `Pulumi.Azure.AppService.HybridConnection` but the RelayId,

```
            var webApiHybridConnection = new HybridConnection(
                    hybridConnectionName,
                    new Pulumi.Azure.AppService.HybridConnectionArgs
                    {
                        AppServiceName = appServiceName,
                        ResourceGroupName = resourceGroupName,
                        RelayId = "how do I find this value?",
                        Hostname = "somehost01.com",
                        Port = 443,
                        SendKeyName = $"{_nameSet.AppServiceName(new ServiceName(ServiceName))}-sk",
                    });
```

How can I find the RelayId using Pulumi.Azure, so I can assign the Hybrid Connection to my App Service?

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with Azure Hybrid Connections, but from looking at the documentation I see a `Azure.Relay.HybridConnection` resource type that allows you to create a Relay HybridConnection to provide into a AppService HybridConnection.

Here's a snippet of the example from https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/pkg/azure/appservice/hybridconnection/#example-usage:

```
var exampleHybridConnection = new Azure.Relay.HybridConnection("exampleHybridConnection", new Azure.Relay.HybridConnectionArgs
{
    ResourceGroupName = exampleResourceGroup.Name,
    RelayNamespaceName = exampleNamespace.Name,
    UserMetadata = "examplemetadata",
});
var exampleAppservice_hybridConnectionHybridConnection = new Azure.AppService.HybridConnection("exampleAppservice/hybridConnectionHybridConnection", new Azure.AppService.HybridConnectionArgs
{
    AppServiceName = exampleAppService.Name,
    ResourceGroupName = exampleResourceGroup.Name,

    /**
     * RelayId from `new Azure.Relay.HybridConnection(...)`
     */
    RelayId = exampleHybridConnection.Id,

    Hostname = "testhostname.example",
    Port = 8080,
    SendKeyName = "exampleSharedAccessKey",
});
```